# Fault in Diff View?

Tags: support

Is this diff view correct? I cannot see any difference between parts of what has been highlighted as changed content.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would be easier to figure out if the suggested edits review let you change the view of the question. In that view, it's not very obvious, but if you look at the **side-by-side markdown view** in the actual revision history, you'll see what changes were made pretty clearly:

[image: Odd spacing]

The user removed all the weird spaces in between all the words.