# Image viewer should expand when zooming in

Tags: feature-request, android-app, images

In the Android tab, if someone posts an image, you can tap it to open it up in a pane like this (screenshots from [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/221667/152515)):

[image: a very narrow image]

This is neat, because it lets you zoom in on the image and pan around on it. Except... when you do so on an image like this, zooming in works like this:

[image: the entire viewing area is still narrow, so we can only see a tiny part of the image]

This is... problematic. Note also that once my thumb's outside this region, the panning doesn't work.

Could the pane expand as the image does until it's (almost) the height and width of my screen, so that I don't have to see the expanded image through a tiny viewport?

Comment: +1; this is extremely annoying.

Comment: +1. *At least an integrated simple image viewer capable of zoom & pan (full screen) Activity wouldn't hurt*

Comment: I (using the app) tapped one of those images to try this out, and it felt really meta.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I'd even rather take this one step more.   I really like the "inline image view" for the first tap, but I would *much* rather zoom and pan with the image viewer I have currently set as the default.

So I'd really love it if tapping on the image a second time used the [`ACTION_VIEW` intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW).

Answer (score 1):

## The issue

The image preview is shown in a browser frame, which can be used to display and load any web page but in this case is used to show images.

It's kind of like viewing an image URL on a desktop browser (especially *Internet Explorer*) where the image is placed at top left at exactly 100% pixel zoom in a white page. This looks terrible in high resolution phone screens as the image is initially shown at an exact pixel-to-pixel rendering on the screen. High density phone screens have very small pixels compared to desktop monitors.

SE's Android app seems to calculate the initial browser frame size from the known size of the image in the post. I noticed that if you zoom in and pan around, *sometimes* the frame would get resized to fill most of the screen.

## My suggestion

I would much rather see the dev team ditch this **"browser style"** image viewer altogether and use a **"galley style"** image viewer instead. The image should be downloaded (it probably already is as it's shown in the post), then shown in a gallery activity or fragment.

The image should occupy the entire screen without distortion, and provide zoom and save capabilities. The background of the gallery viewer must be black, and the action bar must  hide or show when the image is tapped (or hide after short delay).